# Is there any way to "optimize" this simple function? (am I not following best practices?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, optimization

I'm creating a search field that when you type something in to a clear button appears where when clicked will clear what you've been typing. The clear button should go away when you loose focus of the input field however come back if you focus in on the input field and there is something inside it.

The function does not need to be flexible to the sense that the markup structure can vary, the markup structure needs to be    . It just needs to accommodate different selectors.

**Markup:**

```
<div id="searchfield">
      <div id="clearbutton"></div>
      <input name="searchbox" type="text" id="searchbox">
</div>
```

**The JavaScript Function:** *(Note: I'm using jQuery)*

```
function clearableSearchBox(searchbox, clearbutton) {
    var searchbox = jQuery(searchbox);
    var clearbutton = jQuery(clearbutton);

    // When a user starts to enter into the textbox, fade in the clear button
    searchbox.keydown(function() {
        clearbutton.fadeIn('fast');
    });

    // When a user clicks the clear button, remove the contents of the searchbox
    clearbutton.click(function() {
        searchbox.val('');
    });

    // When the textbox is unfocused, fade out the clear button
    searchbox.focusout(function() {
        clearbutton.fadeOut('fast');
    });

    // If there's something in the search box, fade in the close button
    searchbox.focusin(function() {
        if(searchbox.val()) {
            clearbutton.fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
}
```

**Finally, when you want to use the function, call it:**

```
clearableSearchBox("#searchbox", "#clearbutton");
```

Any suggestions on optimization/best practices would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it would be possibly best practice if you use `$` to prefix jquery-variables, eg:

```
function doSomething(selector) {
    var $selector = $(selector);
}
```

otherwise ... nope ... i've spotted nothing to opt ...

you *could* use chaining, eg:

```
searchbox
// When a user starts to enter into the textbox, fade in the clear button
.keydown(function() {
    clearbutton.fadeIn('fast');
})
// When the textbox is unfocused, fade out the clear button
.focusout(function() {
    clearbutton.fadeOut('fast');
})
// If there's something in the search box, fade in the close button
.focusin(function() {
    if(searchbox.val()) {
        clearbutton.fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

but i'm not a big friend of that ... dunno why :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response and insights! :)

Answer (score 2):

Make it a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.clearableSearchBox = function(searchbox, clearbutton) { 
    // all your code here
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$(selector).clearableSearchBox();
```

You can also remove the first argument to the method and use `this` in its place inside your method, as long as the `selector` used in the jQuery method is your searchbox:

```
$.fn.clearableSearchBox = function(clearbutton) { 
    this; // your search box.  
    // inside a plugin, 'this' is already a jquery object, 
    // so there is no need to wrap it with $(this)

    // all your code here
}
```

If you're going to use this pattern, I would recommend generating the clear and close buttons dynamically in your js, to make the plugin as re-usable and easy to use as possible.

For more information about jQuery Plugins checkout the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: the example is not really ... correct ... you should elaborate and provide some working code!

Comment: @Andreas Submitted it early with basic info, then expanded it.  Do I need to clarify it more?

Comment: @Kyle ... hehe ... no problem ... i would love to see the `create the button dynamically` in bold letters and maybe expanded to filling the whole container dynamically - eg: by providing settings you could define the type of the input :)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your input @Kyle and @Andreas. I may consider making it into a plugin then as I will be using this feature in multiple projects!

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for the revision of the $(this) to this and the respective comments.

Comment: np.  Thought I should make sure you have correct information. :)

Answer (score 1):

One more point, you can chain the events binding also.

```
searchbox.keydown(function() {
    // code for keydown
}).focusout(function() {
   // code for focusout
}).focusin(function() {
    // code for focusin
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback rahul. It seems as though chaining is a way to keep code "slimmer" by grouping all possible functions respective one element together, correct?

Comment: @Nathanial yes, and sometimes making it really hard to create event-comprehensive magical-logic :) but in 99.99% of the real-world-usages chaining will be perfect!